# iOS notifications - need to get data from within the app to display in the notification itself

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

Essentially we want users to receive a push notification from us which is basically a text message from a Sender - the message has been sent to us and is to be pushed to the app of a X number of users.

We obviously want to notify the user (Recipient) that they've received a message and also who it's from via the notification before they access the app. "You've received ABC message from XXX" - swipe and they'll be taken to the app. ABC being the content of the message, XXX being the sender's details.

We've got the mobile number of the Sender which we could use to display as the XXX, but more than likely the user has the Sender's name and number stored in their address book and we'd like to display the name of the Sender in the notification if this is the case.

We will have access to the user's iOS contacts from within the app (if they grant us permission) and we'll be keeping a hashed copy of the contacts in order to facilitate friend matching, but we don't want to upload the address book in a readable format to our server (even if we are allowed to).

Is there any way that i can get a notification to the phone and pull data from within the app/phonebook first?

Maybe there's a "silent" notification that can be sent to the app and then the app can provide some sort of internal notification rather than an external push notification (the internal notification will come from the app so it could compare the number in the phone book and pull the name and the name can be displayed in the notification).

Thinking about it, does it matter which notification provider we use?

Will iOS 8 bring any deeper integration that we could use?

ANY suggestions are welcome!!!

Many thanks.

Comment: There's no way to do that unless you associate numbers with names.

Comment: The problem here is that you can never guarantee the app is going to be running when you get the notification. I believe if the app is running in the background, you can intercept the silent notification then generate a local notification with the sender's number translated into a name (assuming the user has given you contact permissions as well). However, if the app is not running in the background, then there's no way to intercept it for a local notification. This is why apps use a username for this type of thing for displaying purposes.

Comment: Also, APN services are all essentially the same. Urban Airship is an easy to use service for their basic notifications (I've had a bunch of issues with their rich pushes), but you can do the same with a little bit more work with your own server. There's 2-3 rails gems out there that do the exact same as Urban Airship that you can use for free if you know how to set it up. Urban Airship just provides nice wrappers and an easy-to-use interface. Same with other notification services.

Comment: As we'll be receiving the messages by text message there's no way to guarantee that every single user is registered with us as anybody in the world could send in a text message.

Comment: @LyricalPanda This is at least a solution. Is there a way to trigger a normal notification if the app is not open in the background and therefore the user can receive a normal notification with the mobile number at least? What's the lowest iOS version that supports silent notifications subsequent local notifications?

Comment: iOS 7 is the first version that could run your app in the background when receiving a push.

If the user hasn't swiped your app from the multitasking screen, you might be able to intercept the push and post your own local notification. I've not fully explored the new background stuff in iOS 7 yet so I could be completely wrong.